# truncate the filname part of a string that is a path.

Tags: python

I have posted an example below and  the desired result . 
I saw a number of ways to eliminate the path section of the file but not the vice versa

**Example .**

```
sample = "/tmp/test/helloworld.cpp"
sample = truncate_file_name(sample)
Print sample
```

**Desired result**

```
/tmp/test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.path` provides the [`dirname` function](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname):

```
>>> from os.path import dirname
>>> dirname("/tmp/test/helloworld.cpp")
'/tmp/test'
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `os.path` functions for things like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.split("/tmp/test/helloworld.cpp")
('/tmp/test', 'helloworld.cpp')
```

Also see `os.path.splitext()`, `os.path.splitdrive()`, and so on. Going the other way, use `os.path.join()` to *construct* paths - it always does the right thing for your operating system.